# How do you continue execution after using trap EXIT in bash?

Tags: bash, exit, trap

**Environment:** GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)

I'm attempting to trap the exit from another function but then continue executing the program.  In an object oriented language you could catch an exception and then continue execution without re-throwin; that is essentially what I'm trying to do.  I'm expecting the function `foo()` to `exit`, but in this case I want to catch it and continue execution of the program.

```
#!/bin/bash

function doNotExitProgram()
{
   echo "Ignoring EXIT"
    # Magic happens here
}

trap doNotExitProgram EXIT

function foo()
{
    echo "Inside foo()"
    exit 170
}

foo
echo "Continue execution here"
```

Expected:

> Inside foo()
> Ignoring EXIT
> Continue execution here

Actual:

> Inside foo()
> Ignoring EXIT

**Steps tried so far:**

1. Tried using `shopt -s extdebug` but that doesn't seem to work with EXIT.
2. Tried `trap - EXIT` inside `doNotExitProgram()`
3. Tried `trap - EXIT` return `return 0` inside `doNotExitProgram()`
4. Tried `trap - EXIT` return `return 1` inside `doNotExitProgram()`
5. Tried `return 0` inside `doNotExitProgram()`
6. Tried `return 1` inside `doNotExitProgram()`
7. Tried `trap "" EXIT` inside `doNotExitProgram()`

This scenario is not described on [Traps on tldp.org](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html) or on the [trap man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html).

**EDIT:** If possible do not change `foo()`

Comment: ideally we would have try/catch in bash: `try exit 1; catch echo got error $?; done; echo continuing the main script`. currently, we can emulate this with subshells, see also [Is there a TRY CATCH command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964529/could-someone-explain-this-try-catch-alternative-in-bash). but currently, there is no native try/catch in bash. there is [try/catch in powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `x` option (`bash -x file`):

```
+ trap doNotExitProgram EXIT
+ foo
+ echo 'Inside foo()'
Inside foo()
+ exit 170
+ doNotExitProgram
+ echo 'Ignoring EXIT'
Ignoring EXIT
```

`trap doNotExitProgram EXIT` happens calling `doNotExitProgram` when called `exit`. When call `foo`, executed `doNotExitProgram`. `exit` finish script execution so not executed `echo "Continue execution here"`.

To resolve:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

(
  function doNotExitProgram()
  {
    echo "Ignoring EXIT"
      # Magic happens here
  }

  trap doNotExitProgram EXIT

  function foo()
  {
      echo "Inside foo()"
      exit 170
  }

  foo
)
echo "Continue execution here"
```

Result:

```
Inside foo()
Ignoring EXIT
Continue execution here
```

With `x` option:

```
+ trap doNotExitProgram EXIT
+ foo
+ echo 'Inside foo()'
Inside foo()
+ exit 170
++ doNotExitProgram
++ echo 'Ignoring EXIT'
Ignoring EXIT
+ echo 'Continue execution here'
Continue execution here
```

You can set a trap in a subshell. The expected value will be output.

Comment: I'm going to hold off accepting incase there's another solution that doesn't involve a subshell.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez Since `exit` terminates the current shell/subshell, the only other way to do this would be to launch a _child shell_ with `bash -c '...'` in place of the subshell in this answer. You'd be waiting a long time for something better.

Comment: I would prefer not changing the existing code, that's why I wanted a `trap` only solution.

Comment: I accepted your answer @sakkke, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Or using helper function:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

function doNotExitProgram()
{
   echo "Ignoring EXIT"
    # Magic happens here
}

function catchExitCode()
{
    case $1 in
        170 )
            doNotExitProgram
            ;;
    esac
}

trap 'catchExitCode $?' DEBUG

function foo()
{
    echo "Inside foo()"
    return 170
}

foo
echo "Continue execution here"
```

You can add a branching function named `catchExitCode`. The drawback is that it can be hijacked if other executables return `170`. By unique exit code, it can branch logic.

Comment: It seems as if you've solved the issue of not exiting from `exit` by removing `exit`.  I don't think this was what the user asked for. Also, could you explain the magic constants 130 (only mentioned in text) and 170?

Comment: Sorry, I missed `130` correctly `170`. And updated answer. I thought cleaner code than using subshell to use `case` statement. But this is a matter of taste.

Comment: Ideally I did not want to have to modify the existing code.  I'll update that more clearer.  +1 for your effort @sakkke

Answer (score 0):

shadow the `exit` command with an `exit` function

similar to the "helper function" solution,
this will not "continue execution" of the main script

"continue execution" of the main script would require goto in bash,
see also [Is there a "goto" statement in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639103/is-there-a-goto-statement-in-bash)

```bash
function evil_function() {
    echo "code before exit"
    exit 1
    echo "code after exit"
}

# shadow the exit command
function exit() {
    local rc=$?
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then rc=$1; fi
    echo "captured exit $rc"

    # no, this would continue "code after exit"
    #return $rc

    # restore the exit command
    unset -f exit

    # continue script here, then exit
    echo "exiting in 5 sec"
    sleep 5

    exit $rc
}

evil_function

# will not continue here
```